# Looking for UX pattern for selection that requires opt-in/opt-out option

Tags: mobile, registration, radio-buttons, settings

I am working on a financial app and struggling with the UX in its settings area. The user needs to select with which method he/she wants to login to the app:

- faceID / fingerprint
- Only password
- username and password.

So far, easy. The problem is that because of regulation reasons, the user needs first to "Register" or "opt-in" to the first two options, and to accept actively to terms. The user also needs to have the option to opt-out from the biometric or the "password only" options, so the app will not store any private details.

It is possible that the user is opted-in to one of the methods, but it is currently not selected.

I am afraid that users will be confused by the duplication of actions - also the option to opt-in/out and the selection.

This is what I have so far (ignore the English. The app is not in English).

[image: Current UX of the settings]

The radio buttons are the selection, and the "Logout" and "Register" starting a flow that ends up back in this screen. If the user clicks on the radio of "Password only" it will start a flow of registration and then will select this option.

Is there a better UX for this? Can you think of an option that will improve the clarity?

Comment: I've removed a "not" from the text, because it seemed to contradict the diagram. However, the diagram isn't clear in some places: if "Face" is not selected at the moment, and the user chooses to use it, why does it follow a "logout/opt-out" flow?